# Need suggestion on Python requirements

Tags: python, web

I need suggestion on what components are required to build a Python based web page to:

1. Take Python code in one Input text box.
   2, Send code output to another text box.
   3, Capable of saving some data (Eg, save code in the input box or future use)

I'm familiar with PowerShell but my experience with web and Python is next to nothing. This web based code execution is my attempt to catch up with both fields.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure to use the excellent and free (even for commercial use) PyCharm IDE - and learn to use the debugger, it is your best friend

Comment: Wead https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming You will probably find that WxPython is thr most popular. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Flask](https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/) is a lightweight Web Server Gateway Interface ([WSGI](https://wsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/what.html)) web application framework. It is designed to make getting started quick and easy, with the ability to scale up to complex applications. It began as a simple wrapper around Werkzeug and Jinja and has become one of the most popular Python web application frameworks. A minimal Flask application looks like this:

Hello world example (hello.py):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Install Flask and run after installing Python 3.x and pip.

```
$ python3 -m pip install Flask
$ python3 hello.py
 * Running on http://localhost:5000/
```

`flask` tag at Stack Overflow